# 3GP shows different preview thumbnail and very large file size?

Tags: video, 3gp

I have a 3GP file and mpg file with the same content from my friend, the 3GP file and MPEG file shows the same resolution, same frame rate, same length and similar quality but I found those two files are different in size, the 3GP file is 1.2G but the mpg file is only 28M.　I also found that the 3GP shows a slightly different preview when I use android movie player. Obviously, this is abnormal and I suspect the file contains several movie or hidden file after editing. I do not have any clue.

Please anyone knows what happened, or any software you know to extract thumbnails or (preview contents). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be virtually anything. If you take a 3GP file and simply concatenate 1GB of garbage data to the end of the file, you'll get a perfectly valid 3GP file that will play, but will be an entire gigabyte larger than it needs to be. The preview could be stored in the exif data and could be set to anything as well, and need not reflect any of the contents of the actual video file itself.

Point is, there's no one answer to your question. You should re-encode the MPEG as a 3GP file if having it available in that format is important to you. You can use free software like ffmpeg or HandBrake to do so fairly easily and how-tos on doing so abound.

Comment: I found that the first 27M is the movie and the rest is another one but join together, I use hex editor to separate them. But another problem come up, the thumbnail is not the same as playing movie, it seems the one before editing, what happened?